# Rotation in the complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, rotations

The function
$f(z) = \frac{(-1 + i \sqrt{3}) z + (-2 \sqrt{3} - 18i)}{2}$
represents a rotation around some complex number $c$. Find $c$.

Hello, 
I am having some trouble trying to do this problem.  I thought of the given equation as a "circle" equation, like $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$, but in complex form.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you will rotate the complex plane with nonzero angle, there will be exactly one point $p $ that will be fixed, $ f(p) = p $.

Another way is as follows: a rotation of angle $ \theta $ about the origin is just multiplication by $ e^{i \theta} $. About a different center $ c $
$$
f(z) = e^{i \theta} ( z - c) + c \\
$$
so you can check a different way.